# collapsing DIV bottom to top

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm not sure how to explain this, but I want to try and get two links that when clicked scroll a hidden `<div>` up to fill the full height of the parent `<div>`. When I try I get problems with it using the full height of the `<BODY>` instead?

```css
    html, body {
      font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      font-size: 13px;
      color: #333;
      background: rgba(0, 109, 189, 1);
      height: 100vh;
      width: 100vw;
      font-family: Calibri, Calibri, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      font-size: 10pt;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    p {
      padding: 10px;
    }
    a {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: blue;
      border: 1px solid rgba(153, 222, 253, 0);
      border-radius: 2px;
    }
    a:hover {
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(40, 28, 253, 1), rgba(22, 24, 25, 1));
      background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(40, 28, 253, 1), rgba(22, 24, 25, 1));
      background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(40, 28, 253, 1), rgba(22, 24, 25, 1));
      background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(40, 28, 253, 1), rgba(22, 24, 25, 1));
    }
    a.nav {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: blue;
      border: 1px solid rgba(153, 222, 253, 0);
    }
    a.nav:hover {
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(40, 28, 253, 1), rgba(22, 24, 25, 1));
      background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(40, 28, 253, 1), rgba(22, 24, 25, 1));
      background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(40, 28, 253, 1), rgba(22, 24, 25, 1));
      background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(40, 28, 253, 1), rgba(22, 24, 25, 1));
      border: 1px solid rgba(53, 22, 53, 1);
    }
    a.dull {
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    #nav {
      /* Left Column */
      margin-top: 5px;
      border-radius: 5px 0px 0px 0px;
      margin-left: 5px;
      margin-bottom: 5px;
      margin-right: 0px;
      line-height: 30px;
      background-color: rgba(24, 24, 24, 1);
      width: 200px;
      border-right: 5px solid rgba(13, 16, 18, 1);
      height: calc(100% - 100px);
      height: -webkit-calc(100% - 70px);
      height: -moz-calc(100% - 70px);
      float: left;
      color: black;
    }
    #footer-nav {
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(50, 19, 25, 1), rgba(37, 75, 29, 1));
      background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(50, 19, 25, 1), rgba(37, 75, 29, 1));
      background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(50, 19, 25, 1), rgba(37, 75, 29, 1));
      background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(50, 19, 25, 1), rgba(37, 75, 29, 1));
      width: 197px;
      font-family: Segoe UI, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      font-size: 7.5pt;
      font-weight: bold;
      height: 28px;
      position: fixed;
      bottom: 5px;
      padding-left: 3px;
      color: #black;
      white-space: nowrap;
      overflow: hidden;
      border-bottom: #7494ad solid 1px;
    }
    #footer-nav:hover {
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(40, 48, 53, 1), rgba(97, 32, 50, 1));
      background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(40, 48, 53, 1), rgba(97, 32, 50, 1));
      background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(40, 48, 53, 1), rgba(97, 32, 50, 1));
      background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(40, 48, 53, 1), rgba(97, 32, 50, 1));
      width: 197px;
      font-family: Segoe UI, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      font-size: 7.5pt;
      font-weight: bold;
      height: 28px;
      position: fixed;
      bottom: 5px;
      padding-left: 3px;
      color: #black;
      white-space: nowrap;
      overflow: hidden;
      border-bottom: #7494ad solid 1px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    #text {
      position: relative;
      top: -4px;
    }
    
    #container {
      bottom: 5px;
      display: none;
      left: 5px;
      position: fixed;
      width: 200px;
    }
    #inner {
      background-color: rgba(20, 7, 7, .4);
    }
    #container2 {
      bottom: 5px;
      display: none;
      left: 20px;
      position: fixed;
      width: 90%;
    }
    #inner2 {
      background-color: #F0F0F0;
      border: 1px solid #666666;
      border-bottom-width: 0px;
      padding: 20px 20px 100px 20px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>CSS Portal - Layout</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/coll.css" />
  <script type='text/javascript'>
    //<![CDATA[ 
    window.onload = function() {} //]]>
  </script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    // When the DOM is ready, initialize the scripts.
    jQuery(function($) {

      // Get a reference to the container.
      var container = $("#container");

      // Bind the link to toggle the slide.
      $("#nav").on("click", "#text",
        function(event) {
          // Prevent the default event.
          event.preventDefault();

          // Toggle the slide based on its current
          // visibility.
          if (container.is(":visible")) {
            // Hide - slide up.
            container.slideUp(200);
          } else {
            // Show - slide down.
            container.slideDown(200);
          }
        }
      );

      // Get a reference to the container.
      var container2 = $("#container2");

      // Bind the link to toggle the slide.
      $("#nav").on("click", "#text2",
        function(event) {
          // Prevent the default event.
          event.preventDefault();

          // Toggle the slide based on its current
          // visibility.
          if (container2.is(":visible")) {
            // Hide - slide up.
            container2.slideUp(200);
          } else {
            // Show - slide down.
            container2.slideDown(200);
          }
        }
      );
    });
  </script>

</head>

    <body>

 <div id="nav">
     <div id="heading-nav">
   A
  </div>
  <div id="container">
   <div id="inner">
    A
   </div>
  </div>
  <div id="container2">
   <div id="inner2">
    B
   </div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer-nav">
   <div id="text">B</div>
  </div>
    </div>
</body>
   </html>
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: *"When I try I get problems with it using the full height of the <BODY> instead?"* Is that a question or a fact?

Comment: A fact sadly. I've changed it around a bit but now it bearly shows up at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Please Put this in your css

```
html, body {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: I've added that but no change.

Comment: please give me your snap shot so i will try better

Comment: I haven't got the reputation to post images but when clicking on the bottom div instead of the inner div appearing full height it appears as a single line above the div you clicked on (probably 30px in height actually but only shows as a single line as the div you click on seems to be positioned above it on the z-index.

Comment: i don't understand acually what you need

Comment: Two menu items which when clicked show two hidden DIVs depending on which was clicked in a parent DIV. So they would slide up to fill the parent DIV.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
#parent{
    width:100px;
    height:500px;
    border:1px solid black;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#booka {
    position:relative;
    background: #3d9a44;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
  }
  #bookb {
    position:relative;
    background: #9a443d;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
  }
#btn1{
    background:orange;
    height:20px;
    width:80px;
}
#btn2{
    background:red;
    height:20px;
    width:80px;
 }
</style>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn1").click(function(){
        if ( $( "#booka:first" ).is( ":hidden" ) ) {
            $( "#bookb" ).slideUp( "fast" );
            $( "#booka" ).slideDown( "fast" );
        } else {
            $( "#bookb" ).slideDown( "fast" );
            $( "#booka" ).slideUp( "fast" );
        }
    });
    $("#btn2").click(function(){
        if ( $( "#bookb:first" ).is( ":hidden" ) ) {
            $( "#booka" ).slideUp( "fast" );
            $( "#bookb" ).slideDown( "fast" );
        } else {
            $( "#booka" ).slideDown( "fast" );
            $( "#bookb" ).slideUp( "fast" );
        }
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="abc">Click on this paragraph.</div>

<div id="parent">
    <div id="booka" hidden>BookA</div>
    <div id="bookb" hidden>BookB</div>
</div>
<div id="btn1">A</div>
<div id="btn2">B</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This seems to be about what I'm looking for just need to merge it with the real webpage.